# Office365 API - App-Only (elevated) Permissions?

Tags: ms-office, office365-apps

Looking at the Office365 API preview, it appears to handle OAuth across services, is there a way to get the app-only token to use for elevated permissions?  For example, what if I want the app to set unique permissions on a file, while the user does not have full-control?  In apps for Sharepoint, this is done by granting full control to the app then using TokenHelper class to get app-only permission.

I don't see that in the Office365 API (preview).  Can it be done?  Or do we still have to include TokenHelper to do elevated permissions?

TIA,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're currently working on an app-only model for OAuth across the Office 365 Services. Hopefully we can deliver this soon in the next couple of month. For now you probably need to still use TokenHelper for SharePoint app-only access.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Assuming 'user3394032' is a MSFT employee, I'll mark this as answer.  PS...why are we not using MSDN forums?